# "Поле чудес" на PHP с использованием скрытого поля hidden

Tags: php

Имеется массив из слов. Из которого выбирается слово рандомно и выводиться в закрытом виде под *. Есть форма, в поле вводиться буква и если она совпадает с буквой в выбранном слове, то буква открывается. Типа "Поле чудес"
Решение должно быть без сессий, с использованием скрытого поля в форме hidden. 
Сделал вот так, но при каждом вводе буквы выводится новое слово. И непонятно как использовать hidden.

```
//массив слов
$words = array ('monitor', 'kot', 'avto', 'karty', 'mikrofon', 'stol', 'internet');
//Выбрать слово наугад
$words_number = array_rand($words, 1);

$word = $words[$words_number];

//Перебираем все буквы слова

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++)
{
    if ($word[$i] == $a)
    {
            echo $word[$i];
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '*';
    }
}

  <form 
    action=""
    method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="a" />
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="OK">    
  </form>
```

Comment: Как правильно тут записать ?
if (empty($_POST['a']))
{
 ???
}

Comment: поле hidden - дырища в безопасности такой игры

Comment: Леонид Якубович, это вы?)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [empty()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php) для проверки пустоты переменной, которую будете хранить в hidden-поле. Т.е. если в hidden-поле из POST-запроса что-то есть, то генерировать новое слово уже не нужно.